# How determine which algorithm has a run-time of log n

Tags: linked-list, runtime

The teacher told us that every time you divide something by 2, the run-time is likely to be log n. For instance, if we divide an array into two, each time we traverse one of the array, the run-time would be log n. However, we may run into a case with LinkedList where we may be easily misled. For instance, we may have an algorithm to find the maximum of the list by starting from either the head or the tail in order to have a run-time of less than n. Logically, we may think that the run time would be log n, but it's not. Why is that? And how do you determine that?

Comment: The complexity is log n if you progressively eliminate half of your items with each step. That's only possible with a sorted list. When searching for an item in a sorted list, you break the list into two each time and discard the list that cannot have the item you're looking for either because its lowest is greater than the search term or its highest is lower.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the front or back (or alternating) does not change the basis of the search for the greatest value. All it does is reorder the search strategy.

If you have a sequential, ordered list and you do a binary search, each comparison reduces the possible locations for a match by 1/2.

If you look at one element of the linked list, each comparison reduces the possible locations for a match by 1 element.

That is a crucial difference.

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake. It's not to find the maximum but to set the nth element to something else.